# Can administrating task of 'root' be divided to the several of "more powerful" users?

Tags: security, root, non-root-user

Unlike `root` (which is able to do everything) is it possible to have multiple administrators assigned to manage only *part* of a system?

For example, one system could have 3 administrators:

- `Application Administrator` - He can install or remove programs, but he cannot change the network settings or add or delete a user
- `Network Administrator` - He can setup the network settings, but he cannot install a program or add/delete users.
- `User Administrator` - He can add or delete users, but he cannot install a program or configure network settings.

The 3 administrators should only be able to administrate the task they are assigned to, so giving them all the `root` account is not desirable because it will enable them to interfere with eachother's jobs.

What's the proper way to approach such a division?

Comment: These people are going to drive each other nuts.  I say **Larry** for applications admin, **Curley** for network, and **Moe** for users.

Comment: You could use `sudo` to limit which programs a user can run..but that would be a pain. Maybe look at some acl stuff

Answer (score 2):

You have to have someone have access to the root account to provide additional privileges. Beyond that, you can use `sudo` to limit effect areas of control for other administrators without giving them root. But overall, what you're describing seems to be more of a political / training issue than a technical issue. Hire the right staff, and they won't get in each other's way, they will help each other out when necessary.

Comment: It would make sense in an environment where nobody trusts anybody else to tell the truth, and so if networking gets messed up there can only be one person to blame.   I agree with you that this does not sound like a very positive approach, but the world is full of not very positive places...

Comment: If nobody trusts anybody else, there are much larger organizational issues that need to be solved before thinking about technical division-of-responsibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

sudo has ways to give users access to some, but not all, commands through sudo.

You can use the `visudo` command to safely edit the /etc/sudoers file, with some syntax checking before the file is really saved.

Inside the file, you can add a line like
`mike ALL=(root) /usr/bin/aptitude, /usr/bin/apt-get`
to give mike access to aptitude and apt-get through sudo, but not any other commands.

Note that this is not very secure. Programs usually assume that if they're being run as root, whoever is running them has full root access, so they don't have special protection against exploits. While the command is running, the user is logged in as root, and there are sometimes tricks to execute arbitrary commands while still being root. You shouldn't do this for users you don't trust, but for your use case, it seems fine.

Details taken from here:
https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/03/01/allowing-limited-sudo-access-with-visudo/

Comment: It can be secure, but You have to be very careful. (and know the system very well)

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is that if a person can arbitrarily install programs then they probably can install a program that will run under root privileges, so they could install programs that would grant them other types of access.  IE any person who can install or modify something that is run as root, is or can easily become root.

If you want to separate out your authentication, you really should be looking at some form of centralized directory service that is only managed by your authentication administrators.  So don't let anyone create local users, and build  a system that deletes/flags any local users that are created.  Then just link all systems to your central directory.

These days most of these task probably should be handled indirectly with a configuration management system whenever possible.  You could then implement some kind of checks on your configuration management system that only permits certain groups to manage certain things.  Perhaps you could simply have some human that approves changes to the configuration management files before they get applied to production systems.  That person would then check that each change is being made by an authorized person.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo would be the tool of choice and you could divide the accesses up by group.

Create the 3 groups you want as administrators add the users you want in each group.

Set your command aliases in /etc/sudoers

> Cmnd_Alias APPADM  = /usr/bin/yum
>   Cmnd_Alias USEADM  = /usr/sbin/useradd
>   Cmnd_Alias NETADM  = /usr/bin/service network *

And then the group accesses

> %appadm   ALL=(root) APPADM
>   %useadm   ALL=(root) USEADM
>   %netadm   ALL=(root) NETADM

Something like that should work.